# Can't find correct version of ruby with rbenv?

Tags: ruby

I am working in OSX El Capitan. I have put the following at the end of my `~/.bash_profile`, and restarted my terminal:

```
export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/var/rbenv
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
```

Then I have run the following, without any errors:

```
brew install rbenv
brew install ruby-build
rbenv install 2.2.2
```

But when I try `ruby --version`  I see:

```
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]
```

What am I doing wrong that means I see Ruby 2.0.0 not Ruby 2.2.2?

These are my paths:

```
~ $ which ruby
/usr/local/var/rbenv/shims/ruby
~ $ which rbenv
/usr/local/bin/rbenv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to change ruby version by following:

`rbenv shell 2.2.2`